# Can't type backslash in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I've just finished installing ubuntu 12.04 and installed  the missed language packages but I strangely can't type backslash as I used to use the button above the windows button, Can't figure out what the problem is and I use this button a lot in programming using eclipse, so what is the problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) said

"Open System Settings > Keyboard Layout and select a layout that matches your keyboard."

When you add a layout to the list of layouts you're interested in you can see each one of them by pressing the button under the list, on the right. In this way you can check that the layout you've picked matches your keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

Open **System Settings > Keyboard Layout** and select a layout that matches your keyboard.

Comment: how would I know the layout that matches my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Language Support` from dash, there you can edit your language options and select the most appropriate language for you.

have a nice day

Comment: from regional format I chose English(United States) but it still doesn't work??

Comment: @Salahuddin Did you tried using backslash with the onscreen keyboard ?

Comment: This question is about keyboard layout, and has nothing to do with Language Support.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings. Select Region and Language sidebar option. The screen displays options to change language and format settings. In the Input Sources option, there is a small keyboard logo which in clicking shows the current layout settings for the keyboard. You can check if it matches the layout of your keyboard. If it doesn't, set a language (region) which matches your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Language-setting alone might not be the issue - there's a specific design choice to do that in some applications. If you have a font with yen-symbol defined at certain points in the character set some apps (hello Chrome/Chromium!) will automatically replace backslash with yen-symbol for you. Super helpful! Exactly what everyone expects.

If you are going in circles with this one, you might want to experiment with font variations. Since this is emulating behaviour that came in with IE6 (though similar behaviour dates back to the days of MS-DOS and code-pages at least!) it is unlikely that this will be fixed any other way soon. If you are getting this with Chromium then you might want to try Firefox, which doesn't do that.